# Insufficient log-delivery permissions when using AWS-cdk and aws lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to create a centralized logging bucket to then log all of other s3 buckets to using lambda and the aws-cdk. The centralized logging bucket has been created but there is an error when using lambda on it to write to it. Here is my code:
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

```
def handler(event, context):
    setBucketPolicy(target_bucket='s3baselinestack-targetloggingbucketbab31bd5-b6y2hkvqz0of')

def setBucketPolicy(target_bucket):
    for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
        bucket_logging = s3.BucketLogging(bucket.name)
        if not bucket_logging.logging_enabled:
            reponse = bucket_logging.put(
                BucketLoggingStatus={
                    'LoggingEnabled': {
                        'TargetBucket': target_bucket,
                        'TargetPrefix': f'{bucket.name}/'
                    }
                },
            )
    print(reponse)



Here is my error:
START RequestId: 320e83c0-ba5e-4d54-a78c-a462d6e0cb87 Version: $LATEST
An error occurred (InvalidTargetBucketForLogging) when calling the PutBucketLogging operation: You must give the log-delivery group WRITE and READ_ACP permissions to the target bucket: ClientError
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Note: Everything works but this log-delivery permission as when I enable it through the aws console it works fine but, I need to do it programmatically! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for S3 logging, you must grant the `Log Delivery` group `WRITE` and `READ_ACP` permissions on the target bucket for logs, and this is done using the S3 ACLs.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/enable-logging-programming.html#grant-log-delivery-permissions-general

When creating a new bucket with CDK, this is set using the `accessControl` property. The default value is `BucketAccessControl.PRIVATE`.

```js
new s3.Bucket(this, 'bucket', {
  accessControl: s3.BucketAccessControl.LOG_DELIVERY_WRITE
})
```

Since CloudFormation has no way to add ACLs to existing buckets this means that CDK also has no such method. With an existing bucket, add `Log Delivery` via the web console, the API, or the CLI with `aws s3api put-bucket-acl`.

Other services, such as CloudFront, don't use ACLs anymore and use IAM policies which can be added using `bucket.addToResourcePolicy()`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3.IBucket.html#add-wbr-to-wbr-resource-wbr-policypermission